# my javascript is not responding because of heavy work

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

My javascript is not responding while working with heavy work.
Here is the example.

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
        ...
    },
    function(callback){
        // orders has over 20K objects
        // this takes over 6 sec
        tickets = _.chain(orders)
            .orderBy(...)
            .map()
            .flatten()
            .filter()
            .value();
    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results){
    ...
});
```

This is very bad for UX and users will often think app is frozen.

How can I solve this problem?

FYI, to implement offline mode, I need to get all details from back-end and save it pouchdb.

Comment: are you getting all 20K orders on 1 API call? If you are- try a pagination approach.

Comment: Not enough details known about your use case

Comment: yes, I'm getting 20K orders in 1 API call and this is not about pagination.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you may want to use a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) or [service worker](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/service-worker/) to run your API call in a separate background thread.

Comment: It's not a api call. it's about calculating the logic on front-end after getting the data from api.

Comment: You can use a web or service worker for that too. It will allow you to split that logic into a separate thread so it doesn't block your UI.

Comment: can I use 3rd library(lodash) in web worker? what about ionic(angular service)?

Comment: Yes i believe you can use other libraries in a web worker via the `self.importScripts` method described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts). The link I provided above for service worker links to ionic's documentation for using service workers.

Comment: Thanks for your support. but I need to use service worker in ionic v1, not 2. is there any example to use angular service or lodash(3rd party library)?

Comment: This seems to be a decent example of using a web worker in angular with lodash loaded into web worker. Should work in ionic 1 too. http://mattslocum.github.io/ng-webworker/demo/